# How to get Mail.app to display (rather than hide) duplicate messages

Tags: mail.app, macos

Prior to Yosemite, setting the following invisible preference would cause Mail.app to show duplicate messages rather than its default behavior of hiding them:

% `defaults write com.apple.mail AlwaysShowDuplicates -bool true`

This no longer seems to have any effect in Yosemite (OS X 10.10).  Does anyone know of an alternate method to achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want this?

Comment: My company has a tight quota on email.  Having duplicate messages with large attachments without my knowledge is detrimental to my staying under that quota.

Comment: Oh and BTW, there is a bug related to this: you cannot drag and drop any message that's hiding a duplicate into a new message as an attachment.  Having the mails displayed individually avoids this problem.

Comment: Three years later and this silly bug still exists in High Sierra.  So I continue to use this invisible preference, and just filed a bug with Apple.  Not that other folks can access it, but it's #35594362.

Answer (score 6):

```
defaults write com.apple.mail _AlwaysShowDuplicates -bool true
```

This should be working.

Comment: I don't know who voted this down, but this does indeed work for me on Yosemite!

Comment: It works on El Capitan too.

Comment: It works on macOS Sierra (10.12) too.

Comment: Works also in Mojave (10.14), and makes painfully obvious how buggy Mail.app can be.